# Error with mysql connection and java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, mysql-connector

I am trying to build a database. The main problem I have is the connection with the mysql database. I have already installed the mysql-connector-java-5.1.38-bin.jar

I have a windows x64 bits and I have searched for a solution but haven't found one yet.

THIS IS MY CODE:

```
package Otros;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class Conexion {
    private Connection conexion;
    private Statement sentencia;
    private static Conexion instancia;
    public static Conexion getInstancia(){
        if(instancia==null){
            instancia=new Conexion();
        }
        return instancia;        
    }
    public Conexion(){
        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            conexion=DriverManager.getConnection("jbdc:mysql://localhost/asistencia_nabajal?user=root&password=");
            sentencia= conexion.createStatement();
        }catch(InstantiationException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(IllegalAccessException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } 
    public ResultSet hacerConsulta (String consulta){
        ResultSet resultado=null;
        try{
            resultado=sentencia.executeQuery(consulta);
        }catch(SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return resultado;
    }
    public void ejecutarSentencia(String consulta){
        try{
            sentencia.execute(consulta);
        }catch(SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public Connection getConexion(){
        return conexion;
    }
    public Statement getSentencia(){
        return sentencia;
    }

}
```

THIS IS THE PROBLEM I GET:

java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jbdc:mysql://localhost/asistencia_nabajal?user=root&password=
Otros.Conexion@5995adb7

Clearly it doesn't allow me to connect to the database, however I don't know why.

Could anyone help me solving this issue?

Comment: classpath issue, no?

Comment: Make sure you run `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();` successfully first.

Comment: `jbdc` != `jdbc`. Fix your url to `jdbc:mysql://localhost/asistencia_nabajal?...`

Comment: @TomN Using `Class.forName` hasn't been necessary for at least ten years (Java 6 / JDBC 4). The calling of `newInstance()` has never been necessary, except as a workaround for a bug in the MySQL driver somewhere 15-20 years ago.

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel  Yes, I know in some case it's unnecessay but not sure about the reason. According to my experience of DB connection by java code, it is necessary to use `Class.forName(Driver)` to connect DB(I tried postgreSQL, MySQL, Oracle). So, it seems not a bad idea to use it.  BTW, my point of previous command is to check driver is work and reachable(seems the issue `No suitable driver found` may cause by classpath option).

Comment: @TomN The cause is simply a typo in the URL; and the OP had `Class.forName`. And `Class.forName` is only necessary if you are working in - for example - Tomcat (or another servlet engine), and the driver is part of the war instead of in the Tomcat lib folder. In all other cases (assuming the driver is JDBC 4+), it is unnecessary.